# Apache Solr queryResultCache

Tags: caching, solr, lucene, solrj

Below is the url which will hit the middle layer then middle layer will form the solr query and fire it.

listing?limit=20&q=Chennai~Tambaram~450000~25000000~24

Chennai-->city

Tambaram-->locality

450000~25000000-->price_min and max

**24--lux_ amenities**

here other than lux_amenities I am using fq for all other things,so the problem here is sorting.

I am sorting the results using bscore and relscore likebelow,

$bscore desc,$relscore desc

first time it works fine.

above bscore and relscore will change based on lux_amenities but lux_amenities is neither part of fq  nor q.So if second time we are changing the lux_amenities alone and firing the query means it is giving the result in same order as first query even the bscore and relscore are different.

So I disabled the queryResultCache,

-->

Now it is working fine. But I need a better solution than disabling this for all queries.For eg, I want to disable this for few queries alone not for all.

Could someone help me please..

Comment: Could you describe how $bscore,$relscore was derived from lux_amenities? by functional query? Did you change the lux_amenities in the solr?

Comment: bscore and relscore are calculated using custom functions like bscore=banorm($lux_amenities,amenities_c,10).lux_amenities is the user input,it will be keep on changing.amenities_c is the indexed and stored field in solr.10 is some constant value.

Comment: I'm not sure if that's expected though(in which solr version?). Maybe you can try "{!cache=false}" to disable the filter cache to see if that help anything.  Note, {!cache=false} may only work in "fq="

Comment: Yes, you are correct  {!cache=false} will work for fq and it may affect the filterCache.But I am looking for a way to disable/enable queryResultCache programmatically. Solr version is 4.6 and I am using solrJ to hit solr.

Comment: I see. Then you might want to consider to put $bscore,$relscore explicitly as  function of lux_amenities in the sort field(perhaps just one will do).